# Pandas: How to make apply on dataframe faster?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, apply

Consider this pandas example where I'm calculating column `C` by multiplying `A` with `B` and a `float` if a certain condition is fulfilled using `apply` with a `lambda` function:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'B':[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]})

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A if x.B > 5 else 0.1*x.A*x.B, axis=1)
```

The expected result would be:

```
   A  B    C
0  1  9  1.0
1  2  8  2.0
2  3  7  3.0
3  4  6  4.0
4  5  5  2.5
5  6  4  2.4
6  7  3  2.1
7  8  2  1.6
8  9  1  0.9
```

The problem is that this code is slow and I need to do this operation on a dataframe with around 56 million rows.

The `%timeit`-result of the above lambda operation is:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop
```

Going from the calculation time and also the memory usage when doing this on my large dataframe I presume this operation uses intermediary series while doing the calculations.

I tried to formulate it in different ways including using temporary columns, but every alternative solution I came up with is even slower.

Is there a way to get the result I need in a different and faster way, e.g. by using `numpy`?

Comment: You should look into `numpy.where`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For performance, you might be better off working with NumPy array and using `np.where` -

```
a = df.values # Assuming you have two columns A and B
df['C'] = np.where(a[:,1]>5,a[:,0],0.1*a[:,0]*a[:,1])
```

---

**Runtime test**

```
def numpy_based(df):
    a = df.values # Assuming you have two columns A and B
    df['C'] = np.where(a[:,1]>5,a[:,0],0.1*a[:,0]*a[:,1])
```

Timings -

```
In [271]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,2)),columns=[['A','B']])

In [272]: %timeit numpy_based(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 380 µs per loop

In [273]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,2)),columns=[['A','B']])

In [274]: %timeit df['C'] = df.A.where(df.B.gt(5), df[['A', 'B']].prod(1).mul(.1))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.39 ms per loop

In [275]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,2)),columns=[['A','B']])

In [276]: %timeit df['C'] = np.where(df['B'] > 5, df['A'], 0.1 * df['A'] * df['B'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 ms per loop

In [277]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,2)),columns=[['A','B']])

In [278]: %timeit df['C'] = np.where(df.B > 5, df.A, df.A.mul(df.B).mul(.1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 ms per loop
```

---

**Closer look**

Let's take a closer look at NumPy's number crunching capability and compare with pandas into the mix -

```
# Extract out as array (its a view, so not really expensive
#   .. as compared to the later computations themselves)

In [291]: a = df.values 

In [296]: %timeit df.values
10000 loops, best of 3: 107 µs per loop
```

Case #1 : Work with NumPy array and use numpy.where :

```
In [292]: %timeit np.where(a[:,1]>5,a[:,0],0.1*a[:,0]*a[:,1])
10000 loops, best of 3: 86.5 µs per loop
```

Again, assigning into a new column : `df['C']` would not be very expensive either -

```
In [300]: %timeit df['C'] = np.where(a[:,1]>5,a[:,0],0.1*a[:,0]*a[:,1])
1000 loops, best of 3: 323 µs per loop
```

Case #2 : Work with pandas dataframe and use its `.where` method (no NumPy)

```
In [293]: %timeit df.A.where(df.B.gt(5), df[['A', 'B']].prod(1).mul(.1))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.4 ms per loop
```

Case #3 : Work with pandas dataframe (no NumPy array), but use `numpy.where` -

```
In [294]: %timeit np.where(df['B'] > 5, df['A'], 0.1 * df['A'] * df['B'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 764 µs per loop
```

Case #4 : Work with pandas dataframe again (no NumPy array), but use `numpy.where` -

```
In [295]: %timeit np.where(df.B > 5, df.A, df.A.mul(df.B).mul(.1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 830 µs per loop
```

Comment: You beat me to it, but `numpy.where` plays well with pandas series, and I believe that my version is more readable ;)

Comment: @IanS OP asked for faster. This brings everything into numpy allowing for more efficiencies.

Comment: @IanS NumPy plays well with number crunching and surely with dataframes, at least that I know! ;)

Comment: I'm getting `1000 loops, best of 3: 255 µs per loop` from this solution, thanks a lot for this.

Comment: I can hardly believe it, the operation on my 56 million row dataframe took around 1 second.

Answer (score 5):

pure `pandas`
using `pd.Series.where`

```
df['C'] = df.A.where(df.B.gt(5), df[['A', 'B']].prod(1).mul(.1))

   A  B    C
0  1  9  1.0
1  2  8  2.0
2  3  7  3.0
3  4  6  4.0
4  5  5  2.5
5  6  4  2.4
6  7  3  2.1
7  8  2  1.6
8  9  1  0.9
```

Comment: nice, prod is faster as mul?

Comment: maybe... barely

Comment: @IanS because it's pure pandas.... slower.  That's why we all raced for numpy. But Divakar beat us too it.  I provided this answer because its different.  Hardly anyone uses `where` from a pandas perspective.  It's interesting because it's assumes the existing values when the condition is `True` or it takes the alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Pandas is a great tool for data manipulation but runs on a single CPU core by default. In addition, Pandas is built to run vectorized API functions on entire columns or datasets in one sweep, but `apply` runs custom user code. The other answers avoid the use of `apply` with custom code but this may not be possible/practical in general. If processing large datasets with `apply` is a pain point for you, you should consider an acceleration and scaling solution such as Bodo. Bodo directly compiles your `apply` code to optimize it in ways that Pandas cannot. In addition to vectorizing your code, Bodo provides automatic parallelization. You can run your code up to 4 cores with the Bodo community edition (which is free to use). Here is a link to the Bodo installation instruction: https://docs.bodo.ai/latest/source/installation_and_setup/install.html

I generated a similar dataset to yours but with 20 million rows and ran the code with regular Pandas on one core and with Bodo on 4 cores. With regular Pandas, it takes about 6.5 minutes to run your code while with Bodo’s community edition it takes around half a second.

```
#data generation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,size=(20000000, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df.to_parquet("data.pq")
```

Regular Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

start = time.time()

df = pd.read_parquet("data.pq")
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A if x.B > 5 else 0.1*x.A*x.B, axis=1)

end = time.time()
print("computation time: ", end - start)

print(df.head())

output:
computation time:  378.3832001686096
   A  B    C
0  3  5  1.5
1  8  6  8.0
2  1  7  1.0
3  8  1  0.8
4  4  8  4.0
```

With Bodo:

```
%%px

import pandas as pd
import time
import bodo

@bodo.jit(distributed = ['df'])
def apply():
    start = time.time()
    df = pd.read_parquet("data.pq")
    df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A if x.B > 5 else 0.1*x.A*x.B, axis=1)
    end = time.time()
    print("computation time: ", end - start)
    print(df.head())
    return df
df = apply()

output:
[stdout:0] 
computation time:  0.3610380489999443
   A  B    C
0  3  5  1.5
1  8  6  8.0
2  1  7  1.0
3  8  1  0.8
4  4  8  4.0
```

Disclaimer: I work as a data scientist advocate in Bodo.ai.

Comment: I tried bodo on my problem and got an error `DataFrame.loc[] getitem (location-based indexing) using Tuple(unicode_type, Literal[int](2020)) not supported yet.`

Comment: didnot work. BodoError: Cannot call non-JIT function 'loads' from JIT function (convert to JIT or use objmode).

Answer (score 3):

Using `numpy.where`:

```
df['C'] = numpy.where(df['B'] > 5, df['A'], 0.1 * df['A'] * df['B'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df.B > 5, df.A, df.A.mul(df.B).mul(.1))
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  1  9  1.0
1  2  8  2.0
2  3  7  3.0
3  4  6  4.0
4  5  5  2.5
5  6  4  2.4
6  7  3  2.1
7  8  2  1.6
8  9  1  0.9
```

Comment: `mul` is not very different from `*`, is it? ;)

Comment: I do some research and it seems if use `df.A*df.B` and `df.A.mul(df.B)` then `mul` is faster. But if multiple by constant, is is same.

Comment: @IanS also, it's convenient for chaining

Comment: Hmmm, here is faster `*`, maybe reason is `np.where` works with numpy arrays.

Comment: It was also a reference to this other time where jezrael beat me to an answer, and the only difference between us was that I used `/` where he had used `div`, which he pointed out made little difference.

Comment: @jezrael I was surprised too, I also expected `mul` to be faster (if not by much).

Answer (score 0):

### pandas 2.2 update: `apply` now supports `engine='numba'`

More info in the [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v2.2.0.html) as well as [GH54666](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/54666)

> Choose between the python (default) engine or the numba engine in apply.
>
> The numba engine will attempt to JIT compile the passed function, which may result in speedups for large DataFrames. It also supports the following engine_kwargs :
>
> - nopython (compile the function in nopython mode)
> - nogil (release the GIL inside the JIT compiled function)
> - parallel (try to apply the function in parallel over the DataFrame)
>
> Note: Due to limitations within numba/how pandas interfaces with numba, you should only use this if raw=True

This is useful for situations where a numpy alternative isn't always obvious. Benchmarking your code on test data is always a useful way to determine if this is working as expected.