# Faster Python implementation from bag of words data frame to array

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, apply

I have a pandas data frame that defines my bag of word indices and counts like this.

```
id      word_count  word_idx
15213   1           1192
15213   1           1215
15213   1           1674
15213   1           80
15213   1           179
307     2           103
307     1           80
307     3           1976
```

I need a *fast* way to return a matrix of bag of words array. Let's say my vocabulary length is 2000: `VOCAB_LEN = 2000`

My current solution is TOO SLOW. But here it is:

*Function*

```
def to_bow_array(word_idx_list, word_count_list):
    zeros = np.zeros(VOCAB_LEN, dtype = np.uint8)
    zeros[np.array(word_idx_list)] = np.array(word_count_list)
    return zeros
```

*Groupby and apply function*

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda row: to_bow_array(list(row['word_idx']),
                                               list(row['word_count'])))
```

This will return my expected output. For every row, something like
`array([0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 2, 0], dtype=uint8)`

I need a faster implementation. I know that `apply` should be avoided for fast implementations. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked `np.where` as suggested here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/41588034/3512538)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need

```
s=df.set_index(['id','word_idx'])['word_count'].unstack(fill_value=0).reindex(columns=np.arange(2000),fill_value=0)
```

Then we convert to tuple ot list

```
s.apply(tuple,1)
Out[342]: 
id
307      (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
15213    (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve your issue:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'word_idx']).sum().unstack()
```

Answer (score 0):

hashing should make it faster - you can use the collections library with its default dictionary as a starter and then build a vector from each dictionary output.

```
word_frequencies = collections.defaultdict(int)
for word in words:
 if word not in dictionary:
    dictionary[word] = len(dictionary)
    word_frequencies[dictionary[word]] += 1
```

and what you need at the end is the `word_frequencies.items()`