# Optimizing multiple for loop with Lambda function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a below data frame `Df1` with Columns 'Summary' and 'Closing group'

```
Summary                         Closing Group
XX012 job abended with error    Automation
XX015 job abended with error    Automation
Front End issue TSL error       Automation
XX015 job abended with error    Automation
Front End issue TSL error       Automation
Front End issue TSL error       Automation
File not present error          Automation
```

I have another data frame `Df2` below with column 'Label'

```
Label
TSL error
job abended
File not present
```

I want to map each `Label` against `Summary` column if exact string from `Label` exist in `Summary`.

I have written the below script to handle my condition using `for loop`:

```
list_label= Df2['Label']

def is_phrase_in(phrase, text):        
    return re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(phrase), text, re.IGNORECASE) is not None

for idx2,row2 in Df1.iterrows():       
    for label in list_label:
        print(label)
        if is_phrase_in(label, row2['Summary']):
            Df1.at[idx2,'Label'] =label
            break
```

The above code gave me the expected results but its taking much time when run on `7000 label` list and `20000 Summary`.

To optimize this I have used `Lambda` function as below :

```
Df1['Label'] = Df1['Summary'].apply(lambda x : next((l for l in list_label['Label']  if is_phrase_in(l,x)), 'No Label Found'))
```

But this script take more time , even more than if `for loop`.

Can anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong here or is there any other way to optimize this code.

My expected output:

```
Summary                         Closing Group      Label
XX012 job abended with error    Automation         job abended
XX015 job abended with error    Automation         job abended
Front End issue TSL error       Automation         TSL error
Server down error               Server             No Label found
XX015 job abended with error    Automation         job abended
Front End issue TSL error       Automation         TSL error
Front End issue TSL error       Automation         TSL error
File not present error          Automation         File not present
```

Comment: You can actually try numpy or panda. They are naturally faster because they have optimized engines for data frames. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588034/pandas-how-to-make-apply-on-dataframe-faster

Comment: Do you really have 7,000 unique, potentially valid labels for only 20,000 data points? Having to search each of those many, many labels for each data point expands the time requirements greatly - if you can optimise your labels list (hard to understand if possible without context) then this could be greatly beneficial

Comment: Yes, I have approximately 7000 unique labels.

Comment: May I kindly suggest that this is very easily parallelizable ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - Did you mean Multi threading? if not then can you share the link for parallelizable

Comment: Multithreading won't do much good in Python (for this kind of stuff at least). I'm talking either multiprocessing (easiest option, no external dependencies, but cannot be distributed) or some distributed computing framework (map/reduce, celery, whatever - much heavier setup, and probably overkill here IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

It must be clear that most of the processing in the above code would be spent on the regular expression search (re.search).

Can you try for the alternative 'Python String find() Method' .i.e. str.find(str, beg=0, end=len(string)) with your data.

```
if text.find(phrase) == -1:
   return 'No Label Found'
else:
   return phrase
```

Comment: Yeah I just did a test of `re.search(r"\bA test\b", "this is a test you know", re.IGNORECASE)` vs `"A test".lower() in "this is a test you know".lower()` and the regex was an order of magnitude slower (~2.5s vs ~0.15s)

Comment: This will not give me the exact string match. For example I have a `phrase =' Frequent' ` and `text = 'Frequently occur error'`, the above script will give me output as `Frequent` but in my case I do not want this as its not exact match. That is the reason I was using regex.

Comment: @Oliver.R - I have change the string to lower in both phrase and text but still it takes much time.

Comment: `' Frequent' in 'Frequently occur error' == False` - the leading space in the phrase distinguishes it. If the space is not meant to be there and you're saying that `Frequent` is a subset of `Frequently` and therefore you require the word barrier - that's an expensive operation to determine, and I think it makes more sense to re-think whether what you're doing is the most efficient way of doing it. In regards to string lowercase, I don't just mean changing strings to lowercase, I also mean using `in` instead of a regex solution - it's an order of magnitude faster, but you're comparing too much.

Comment: @Oliver.R -Let me tell You another case .My labels contain values like `'XXX015FS'` and `'XMLerror'` and my text contains one value as  `'XXX015FS XMLerror404 error occured'`. Now if I use my script using `re.search` function, it will give me label as 'XXX015FS' but if use `re.find` it can give me `'XXX015FS'` or `'XMLerror'` either of the two. I have many cases like this. That is the reason I am very particular about exact string match. Although my code runs perfectly fine and gave me expected output, but its taking approx 55 min on 7000 labels and 20000 summary.

Comment: split the text into tokens, trim and join with a leading and training white space and use the 'find' method. are there counter examples for this

Answer (score 0):

The replacing of comparison of strings using "in" instead of regex makes the code a little bit faster. But however from the example that you have provided, it seems that the summaries are repeating("XX015 job abended with error" occurred two times and "Front End issue TSL error " occurred three times). Maybe you can take the set of unique summaries and labels and do your string operations, store them somewhere else as dictionaries and then do the final mapping. I guess this makes it a lot faster compared to directly computing the function each time you see the strings.

Comment: So your iteration would be on unique summaries and not on the Df1. Things would be lot faster depending upon the number of rows in Df1 and number of unique summaries in Df1.

Comment: honestly I have 20000 unique summary only labels are kind of common among them , that is the reason I am mapping those summary against labels