# What is an efficient method using pandas for retrieving data with a given start/end point when the datapoints also have start/end points?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am currently developing an application which leverages genomic count data. This data is loaded into a pandas dataframe. An example of this data would look like this:

| chrom | chromStart | chromEnd | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr3 | 93504854 | 93504940 | 0 |
| chr3 | 93504940 | 93504977 | 1 |
| chr3 | 93504977 | 93505016 | 2 |
| chr3 | 93505016 | 93505018 | 1 |
| chr3 | 93505018 | 93505053 | 2 |
| chr3 | 93505053 | 93505093 | 1 |
| chr3 | 93505093 | 93505151 | 0 |
| chr3 | 93505151 | 93505227 | 1 |
| chr3 | 93505227 | 93505252 | 0 |
| chr3 | 93505252 | 93505328 | 1 |

I currently have an implementation of the title which accounts for quite a bit of my time taken. Here is the implementation:

```py
def checkInBounds(row, chrom, chromStart, chromEnd):
    try:
        if not chrom == row['chrom']:
            return False
    except KeyError:
        print('row count', row.count)
        print("CheckInBoundsKeyError\nRow\n", row, '\n chrom', chrom, 'start', chromStart, 'end', chromEnd)
        return False

    if chromStart <= row['chromStart'] <= chromEnd:
        return True
    elif chromStart <= row['chromEnd'] <= chromEnd:
        return True
    else:
        return (row['chromStart'] < chromEnd) and (row['chromEnd'] > chromEnd)
```

This is ran using an apply statement which looks like this:

```
df.apply(checkInBounds, axis=1, args=(chrom, start, end))
```

Is there a faster way to accomplish this same task?

Comment: Check this faster alternative to df.apply() https://stackoverflow.com/a/41588095/7987118

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the [searchedsorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) function in pandas Series. In a sorted Series, it tells you where you should put the value you pass to keep the data sorted.

Using your function on your data I get:

```
chrom = 'chr3'
start = 93504854
end = 93505053
df = df.sort_values(['chrom','chromStart','chromEnd'])
df.apply(checkInBounds, axis=1, args=(chrom, start, end))

    0     True
    1     True
    2     True
    3     True
    4     True
    5     True
    6    False
    7    False
    8    False
    9    False
```

Here is the function with search sorted.

```
def checkInBounds_new(df, start, end, chrom):
    bound1 = df.chromStart.searchsorted(start)
    bound2 = df.chromStart.searchsorted(end)
    df =  df.loc[bound1:bound2]
    return df[df['chrom'] == chrom]
checkInBounds_new(df, start, end, chrom):
```

which gives you:

```
chrom   chromStart  chromEnd    height
0   chr3    93504854    93504940    0
1   chr3    93504940    93504977    1
2   chr3    93504977    93505016    2
3   chr3    93505016    93505018    1
4   chr3    93505018    93505053    2
5   chr3    93505053    93505093    1
```

Notice how both functions basically returns the first 5 rows for these inputs. Also, I didn't implement any checks here like making sure that end > start and so on.