# How to improve performance of pandas.apply() to perform text cleaning operations on large sized pandas column?

Tags: pandas, numpy, performance, tweets, pandas-apply

I'm working on a tweet dataset where one column is the text of the tweet. Following function performs the cleaning of tweet which involves removal of punctuations, stopwords, lower case conversion, removal of emojis and these are themselves a small utility functions.

```
def clean_text(text):
    text = text.lower().strip()
    text = remove_punct(text)
    text = remove_emoji(text)
    text = remove_stopwords(text)
    
    return text
```

I'm creating a new column for the cleaned text:

```
df['clean_text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))
```

This is becoming painfully slow as the dataset grows in size. Numpy.where() provides [significant performance improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588034/pandas-how-to-make-apply-on-dataframe-faster) for filtering the data. How do I speed above apply operation either using map() or numpy.where() or something else?

Comment: Why do you think `np.where` is useful here?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is that' why linked the relevant question. Trying to understand if there is any way pd.apply() can be improvement in the textual transformation I have mentioned. Any corrections in my understanding are appreciated.

Comment: You can use `df['text'].str.lower()` as first step.

Comment: What do you want to clean for punctuation?

Comment: Remove all punctuations.

Comment: What happens if you have an url in the tweet like `https://www.google.com/search?q=noluck&source=hp`? And for `#` and `@`?

Comment: The purpose right now is not to fine tune the cleaning operations and handle all cases like the one you have mentioned. If you have any input related to actually speed up the apply() operation, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's important because like `df['text'].str.lower()` other operations can be realized in a vectorized way and increase the speed. If you don't want that, use `Dask` or `multiprocess` module to speed up your code.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to tweak the function itself, you can use Pandarella to parrallize your apply https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel. It even gives you a nice progress bar :)